# How long will it take the number of bacteria to double?

Tags: exponential-function

> The number of bacteria in a strain is given by $B(t) = 30e^{1.5t}$,
>   where $t$ is the time in hours.
>
> a) How many bacteria are there at time zero?
>
> b) How long will it take the number of bacteria to double?

a) $30e^{1.5t} = 30e^0 = 30$

b) $30e^{1.5t} \ge 2$

$\implies e^{1.5t} = \frac{1}{15}$

$\implies 1.5t = \ln(\frac{1}{15})$

This gives a minus number.

Comment: Note the word *double* here. It's not $2$ but $2B(0)$.

Comment: You have a negative number because if at time 0 you have 30, at some time in the *past* you *had* 2.  Notice you don't want an **absolute** amount of 2.  You want a *double* the amount of 30.  Technically you want to solve for: $\frac {30e^{1.5t}}{30e^0} = 2$.

Comment: In general... B (t)=A$e^{ct} $.  Means A is the initial population and $e^{ct} $ is the factor of growth.  So you want to simply solve $e^{ct}=2$ which should have the same solution regardless of whatever the initial population was.

Comment: @fleablood great point and very useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) okay : $30~e^{1.5~(0)}=30$

b) You want the time when this is doubled: $30 \, e^{1.5 t}=60~$

$$t = \dfrac{\ln 2}{1.5} $$